# how can I install and use expect on android for an automated ssh conection?

Tags: android, ssh, expect, scp

I am trying to use SCP over ssh between an android HTC and a linux machine thrpugh wifi, and I need the connection to be established automatically. After trying diffrent methods, I want to use expect in order to emulate the prompt's request for the password. How do I install expect and TCL on a rooted android 2.3 device?